# Why is a permission exception thrown in a parent EJB class when @RolesAllowed are the same?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.1

A servlet is calling a method of an EJB (name EJB B). EJB B is a sub class of EJB A which contains the method and is not overridden by EJB B.

EJB A uses the annotation @RolesAllowed({"user","system","admin"})

EJB B uses the annotation @RolesAllowed({"system"})

When the call is made by the servlet the following error is produced:

JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component EJB B for method xxxx: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: xxxx throws exception of bean: EJB B is not allowed

If I replace the EJB A annotation with @PermitAll then the method is called without the permission problem.

I am wondering why the 'system' role allowed in EJB A is ignored in the annotation and the exception is thrown.

Comment: Class-level annotations should only apply to methods defined in that class, so this sounds like a product defect. I recommend reporting it to product support.